# When did I reset the data counter on my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, cellular-data, time-tracking

Is it possible to see some detailed statistics about data usage on an iPhone (iOS 8)? In the System Preferences I can only see that I have consumed 8 GB data and 23 h of calling, but I can't see when these numbers was reset last time, average usage per month and similar details that would be useful now when I consider changing plan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean the usage on the mobile network, it is shown in Settings -> Mobile network, all the way down, scroll down to see when it's been reset.